# How to avoid a large number of user controls on a form

Tags: c#, winforms, performance, user-controls

I'm creating a user control that represents a list of other custom controls (they are pretty simple: include label, checkbox, icon and button). When I place it on a form it takes to long to load all of the list items (there are 100 - 150 items in a list). What are the alternative ways for displaying a list of custom controls of a large number?

I tried to use SuspendLayout and ResumeLayout but it didn't help much, using them reduces the time, but its still too long.

There are some ideas I cannot implement for various reasons:

- somehow to work only with items that fall into a view (how to ignore others?)
- implement Grid control behaviour - create custom control only in edit mode, but it is difficult to paint the others

Grateful for any advice

**EDIT:**

There were a few suggestions to use a DataGridView. This is a good idea, but the problem is that the custom control can change it's size and show additional information below (it behaves like expander). It's not easy to do with DataGridView

Comment: Create a UI design that doesn't require a large number of controls on the screen at once? :D

Comment: @ShaneC I'd love to! But it I'm asked to show a 100-150 items in a screen and I don't have another choice but to create a custom control for each of them. Should I use paging? I haven't seen it in winforms

Comment: Sounds like a god form. You might want to use multiple forms instead.  It's scientifically proven that too many controls on a form makes the users brain melt.

Comment: The fact that `SuspendLayout` and `ResumeLayout` had some measurable effect makes me think that you've written layout code somewhere other than the *constructor*, like say the `Load` event handler method? Always place initialization code in the constructor so that Windows doesn't have to (re-)create the controls multiple times based on the properties that you set.

Comment: @Cody Gray The problem is that I'm getting required information about what those items should be after the form was created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @Cody, but, in case "stripping some of the ones that you have out" isn't an option... let me take it one step further...

You mentioned you have a list.

I'd take a hint out of the iOS playbook, and only have the number of controls active that you need to display the list on the screen.

For example; If the list has room for 30 items on the screen, you can re-use the same 30 controls as the user scrolls / pages through the list.

Which brings up another point - sometimes slightly modifying the navigation is a good bet. If you have one huge list now, maybe a "paging" features where you only display x number of items per "page" is something to consider.

Regardless, when you get to this point in an application, and you have real world loading speed / memory usage performance requirements, it's time to crack out the old book on performance tuning, and implement proven patterns like re-use, caching, etc.  It's usually not always pretty, and it makes your solution more complex, but you do what you need to do to make it work right.

Comment: Ehh, it's unlikely that (your last paragraph) is actually going to help. Windows has to create all of those controls before it can display them on the screen. Each one of those controls (and sometimes sub-controls *within* those controls) represents a native "window" (yes, Windows is made up of "windows", how clever those programmers were), and that doesn't come for free. It's very unlikely that even the most performant code in your application is going to make a difference here. The usual tricks will be thwarted. The only solution is to minimize the number of controls you create. Period.

Comment: @Cody; I couldn't disagree with you more (or, maybe we're saying the same thing). Re-use of existing controls (as I mention in my last paragraph) will absolutely help, as the system doesn't have to reallocate and recreate the associated memory, window handles, etc.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I clarified that I was specifically responding only to your last paragraph. Re-using existing controls is definitely the right idea.

Comment: @Cody; the last paragraphs says: "it's time to crack out the old book on performance tuning, and implement proven patterns like re-use [...]"

Comment: I guess I'm reading more into this than you meant to imply, then. Breaking out the book on performance tuning makes me think of algorithms and Donald Knuth, not reusing window handles. ;-)

Comment: Thanks, I think "paging" is the way to go

Answer (score 2):

If you are tied to WinForms, then I highly recommend that you use a DataGridView instead.  I ran into the same issues a while ago, and found that the DataGridView was extensible enough to list all sorts of controls (TextBoxes, CheckBoxes, even DateTimePickers, etc).  Transitioning to this control sped up my UI tremendously, and was more stable and easier to maintain.

If you need more advanced facilities in each row, like the Expander properties you mentioned, then I think you should look into WPF.  With WPF you have tremendous flexibility to completely design your UI controls the way you want them, and the performance is still very good.

If neither of these work for you, then how about redesigning your UI?  As mentioned, there is no way to alleviate the performance hit for a large number of controls.  So how about show one row or only a few rows at a time, with a filter or search facility to allow the user to find the row(s) they want.  Or, show all rows but only use minimal controls in each row, and have the user doubleclick on the row to bring up a dialog window to display more detailed information about the row?  Some way or another you'll have to cut down the number of controls initially displayed.  These are just a few ideas.

Comment: This is a really good idea, but there is one problem. I'll update my question

Comment: @Sorin Comanescu VirtualMode implies that I will manually paint everything else. That's the problem I described as the second idea a can't implement

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there's no way to get something for nothing. Things in life don't come for free. If you have an unreasonable number of controls on your form, you'll have to pay for the time it takes to load them. The only option is to use fewer controls.

Whether you accomplish that by stripping some of the ones that you have out, or by custom drawing lighter versions of the built-in counterparts, is up to you. But I *highly* recommend that you stick with the native controls and just ditch a few of the ones you're using now.

In addition to the obvious performance problems, the scenario you've described is guaranteed to create a User Overflow error, one that no debugger can fix.

Answer (score 0):

Use a DataGridView and customize columns?

Comment: That was an option, but my custom control can change it's size (in essence it is an expander that has a title and shows some additional information). When the user clicks the button it should expand it's content. It's not easy to do in grid